# Django ghost settings.py file when separating production/development settings

Tags: django

I am at my wits' end with this problem and I am hoping one of you kind folks have the answer. The traceback hits a file that does not exist!

I have production and development Django apps - so I am trying to utilize the settings argument on `manage.py` to access the right settings when running `manage.py` ie `python manage.py runserver --settings=athena.settings.development`

To make this work - I moved my `settings.py` file with the nasty `if`/`else` construct and some print statements just to make sure the the settings would still read it there was following me to `settings/base.py`. I created a settings directory and moved/renamed the `settings.py`.

```
athena/
 |-- athena/
 |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |-- settings/
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- base.py    <------
 |    |-- urls.py
 |    +-- wsgi.py
 +-- manage.py
```

the new `settings/base.py` that manage.py can't read - defaults to the old `settings.py` as you'll see in the traceback:

```
import os

from decouple import config

# BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
print ('-----------')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', cast=bool)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['athe.herokuapp.com',
                 '127.0.0.1']

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'athena_app.apps.AthenaAppConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'athena.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'athena.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

if os.environ['PROD_DB_NAME'] in os.environ():
    print ('-----------------base')
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': config('PROD_DB_NAME'),
            'USER': config('PROD_DB_USER'),
            'PASSWORD': config('PROD_DB_PASSWORD'),
            'HOST': config('PROD_DB_HOST'),
            'PORT': config('PROD_DB_PORT')
        }
    }
else:
    print ('------------------BASE')
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['DEV_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['DEV_DB_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['DEV_DB_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['DEV_DB_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['DEV_DB_PORT'],
        }
    }

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
# python athena/manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# destination of collectstatic command
STATIC_ROOT = 'https://athena-heroku.herokuapp.com/static/athena_app'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "athena_app/static/athena_app")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'athena_app/static/athena_app'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

LOGIN_URL = '/login'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users//ct-venv/ct-webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users//ct-venv/ct-webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users//ct-venv/ct-webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users//ct-venv/ct-webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users//ct-venv/ct-webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users//anaconda/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users//other_projects/database/athena/athena/settings.py", line 96, in <module>
  File "/Users//ct-venv/ct-webapp/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DEV_DB_USERNAME'
```

The traceback refers to a settings file that does not exist! it is referring to a file that has been moved. I have tried to comment out references to `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in `wsgi.py` and `manage.py` and `unset` the same in my `.env` to no avail. I need to be able to change the reference before I move forward. `python manage.py runserver --settings=athena.settings.development` AND `python manage.py runserver --settings=athena.settings` get the same result.

Comment: is there still a .pyc file in the directory?

Comment: YES. good grief

Comment: @PaulBecotte also was missing in underscore in the init file, cheers

Comment: fyi: you can get rid of that if statement by making a config file for each environment and having wsgi.py read the django_settings_module from the config file.

Comment: thanks @BradenHolt I did something similar - defined two settings files and pass a settings argument to `manage.py`